# Location of adt plugin

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

Hi all I want to know where on disk adt plugin is installed.I downloaded the whole package from [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com) then i updated it to API-19 but now it has stopped working it shows an error Dependency Confliction .
Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

By default adt plugin get install in your eclipse plugins directory "~/eclipse/plugins/"

Answer (score 0):

For the ADT to work normally you need to set the path where the bin folder is present .

This path is to be set under the Project>Properties>Android. 
If the path is configured properly then you can see all the installed packaged (Android 1.2 to the Android 4.4).

If not set then you can set by

1. In the "Welcome to Android Development" window that appears, select
   Use existing SDKs
2. Browse and select the location of the Android SDK directory you
   recently downloaded and unpacked.
3. Click Next.

Answer (score -1):

Download the ADT Plugin from....
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Comment: that doesn't give the solution when i go to Install New Software then shows error conflict dependency